# jQuery and event bubbling: stop unwanted events

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I am trying to enhance a HTML textarea with some BB-Code controls that should only be available when the textarea has focus. The desired behaviour looks like this:

**Picture 1 - before focus event:**
[image: before focus event]
<sub>(source: [gaedekenet.de](http://gaedekenet.de/tmp/beforeInit.jpg))</sub>

**Picture 2 - after focus event (correct behaviour):**
[image: correct behaviour]
<sub>(source: [gaedekenet.de](http://gaedekenet.de/tmp/afterInit.jpg))</sub>

The above correct behaviour is accomplished by clicking in the LOWER part of the textarea - where no buttons will appear. But whenever the user clicks in the top left part of the textarea, the following will happen:

**Picture 3 - after focus event (incorrect behaviour):**
[image: erroneous behaviour]
<sub>(source: [gaedekenet.de](http://gaedekenet.de/tmp/afterInit_error.jpg))</sub>

It seems to me that not only the "focus" event is triggered but also "click", "mousedown", "mouseup", etc.

What I need to do now, is to stop the event propagation in my own code (the focus part) so that no events can reach the BB Code plugin (which is a 3rd party plugin). My current approach looks like this:

```
$(#myText)
    .focus(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation().stopImmediatePropagation();
        // initialize and show the bb code buttons here
    })
    .click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation().stopImmediatePropagation();
    })
    .mouseup(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation().stopImmediatePropagation();
    })
    .mousedown(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation().stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try e.preventDefault() ?

Answer (score 1):

`e.stopPropagation()` stops propagation, to prevent default events use

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Full jQuery event API documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Comment: Thanx, e.preventDefault() turned out to be the core of my solution. 

But to reach perfection (correct handling of focus and click events in a huge array of above textareas) I also had to create a rather complex set of event listeners that depend on each other. The solution I came up with took me 6 hours and ruined my day. But it's done :-)